# Delphi: How to load the contents of the table (mysql) into an Array [1..50] of Float?

Tags: mysql, arrays, delphi, mydac

I have a table in a datasource module using MyDAC. I want to load the contents of the table, column months with 50 rows into an Array [1..50] of Float. How can I do this?

This is the code of my datamodule unit:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Data.DB, DBAccess, MyAccess, MemDS;

type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    MyConnection1: TMyConnection;
    MyQuery1: TMyQuery;
    MyQuery1Months: TFloatField;
    MyQuery1Qob: TFloatField;
    MyQuery1Qcalc: TFloatField;
    MyDataSource1: TMyDataSource;
    MyTable1: TMyTable;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Comment: How much do you already know about using MyDac?  There are a few different steps to this; where in the process are you getting stuck?

Comment: I'm new in work with DB, I'm put my datamodule code @MasonWheeler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a table with 3 columns, each of which is typed Float.  (Though I can't help but wonder why a column called "months" would contain floating-point data.)  You wouldn't load that data into an array of 50 floats; you'd load it into an array of 50 records or objects containing 3 fields.

But let's say you only wanted to load the values of one of the fields.  That would go something like this:

```
i := 1; //index variable into the array
myQuery1.Open; //run the database query
while not myQuery1.EOF do //loop until we reach the end of the dataset
begin
   myArray[i] := MyQuery1Qcalc.value; //read the field value to the array
   myQuery1.Next; //next record
   inc(i); //next array index
end;
```

Be aware that if this result set contains a different number of records than the expected 50, you'll have trouble.  It might be better to use a dynamic array and set its length equal to the dataset's `RecordCount` property after calling `Open`.  But that's the basic pattern for loading data: open the dataset, (or call `First` on it if it's already open,) then read values from the fields and call `Next` until you reach the `EOF` (End Of File, which in this case actually means End Of Record Set.)

Comment: Hello thanks, it worked. I just had to add "DataModule1". Myquery1.Open. 

My data are all double and months are integers (numbers are because of months). 

My variable MyArray got the right size and with 50 rows of data.

Now I have to recode to C++ in Builder, bye and thanks again!

Comment: I would have expected `DataModule2` ... but the intention is to put this code into the datamodule itself or build a function `function GetFloatFieldValues( ADataSet : TDataSet; const AFieldName : string ) : TArray<double>`

Comment: Exacly DataModule2, sorry.@Sir make a function with @Mason code, right?